# ActiveSheet.Paste type (Paste Only values)

Tags: copy, copy-paste

I have this simply code, I want to copy only values from WoorkBook1 into Workbook2, only values, because Workbook2 have a specific format.

```
Sub Test()
   Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx").Activate
   Range("B2:B7").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsx").Activate
   Range("B5:B10").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Tnx4all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`PasteSpecial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) with the `xlPasteValues` option

```
Sub Test()
   Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx").Activate
   Range("B2:B7").Select
   Selection.Copy
   Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsx").Activate
   Range("B5:B10").Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I will do it in 6 min exactly! :)

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way of doing it:

```
Sub Test()

Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsx").Activate
Range("B2:B7").Copy
Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsx").Activate
Range("B5:B10").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```